# Automapper Open Generics

Tags: c#, generics, automapper

I'm trying to use Automapper's Open Generics as described in https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Open-Generics to perform a mapping between `Translated<T>` and `T`.

```
public class Translated<T>
{
    public T En { get; set; }
    public T Fr { get; set; }
}
```

I've create a TypeConvertor for it

```
public class TranslatedConverter<T> : ITypeConverter<Translated<T>, T>
{
    public T Convert(Translated<T> source, T destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        // Conversion logic
        return source.En;
    }
}
```

Can somebody help me out how to create a profile for it

```
CreateMap<Translated<>,???>().ConvertUsing(new TranslatedConverter<>());
```

Comment: Use `object` as the destination.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu how exaclty would you write the CreateMap?

Comment: Because when I Use
CreateMap(typeof(Translated<>), typeof(object)).ConvertUsing(typeof(TranslatedConverter<>));
I get a
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'TranslatedConverter`1[System.Guid]' to type 'AutoMapper.ITypeConverter`2[Translated`1[System.Guid],System.Object]'.

Comment: The converter doesn't match the map, that's what the message is telling you.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu the reason why it is giving this error is because, as you told me, I've put object as a mapping destination.
Can you give me the exact syntax for the profile so it will have a open generic mapping to T.

Comment: I'd rather not do that. You should be able to understand why your converter is wrong. Because if you don't, you're better off not using AM at all. Just write the manual mapping.

Comment: @NikoDierickx did you ever figure out the correct mapping configuration?

Comment: @Mr.T No, I did not